# Swift xpath search return string

Tags: ios, swift, xpath

For example at this page:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Arnold-Universal-Snow-Thrower-Key-Set-4-Piece-490-241-0008/202251530?keyword=4902410008

We use this xpath:

```
concat(//*[@id='ajaxPrice']/text(), //*[@id='ciItemPrice']/text())
```

I have tried all libs in swift that working with xpath:

https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

https://github.com/topfunky/hpple

https://github.com/honghaoz/Ji

Always get empty results. They all not working if i will return string as result of xpath query. Any ideas how i can return string but not `XMLElement` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your XPath query on this Swift library called [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi) ( https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi ) and it returns '$7.98'. (Whitespaces are not trimmed so you might need to add that yourself)

Similar to the 3 libraries you listed Fuzi is also a wrapper of libxml2.

Here's my code

```
import Fuzi
let document = try? HTMLDocument(string: htmlString)
if let result = document?.eval(xpath: "concat(//*[@id='ajaxPrice']/text(), //*[@id='ciItemPrice']/text())") {
    print(result.stringValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2 I think it's better to use [`string-join`](http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_2.html#Functions~string-join) instead, like in the following example:

```
string-join(//*[@id='ajaxPrice']/text(), //*[@id='ciItemPrice']/text())
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: this is not working... Because all libraries want to return element with xpath for them, like: ```//a[starts-with(@href, "buy.php/")]```, then xpath functions working. But for example: ```normalize-space(//a[starts-with(@href, "buy.php/")])``` - not working